# Firebase e Java

Tags: firebase, nodes, double-quotes

Why in some cases, the firebase node is created as a string with double quotes "" and in another cases as a string with no quotes.

for example:
----dates
|
022022--
|
"022022"--

Thanks for the help

Comment: Show us a concrete example.

Comment: To get your Firebase structure, use the Firebase console->Export JSON and copy and paste a snippet of your structure. Then include the code you're using to write that Firebase data.

Comment: i solved the problem simply adding the .trim() method to myString before putr the save command.

Answer (score -1):

I solved the problem by simply adding the `.trim()` method to `myString` before calling the save command. Example:

```
movimentacoes_ref =  firebaseref
                    .child("movimentacao")
                    .child(id_Usuario)
                    .child(mesAno); // give me a "mesAno" node in firebase.
```

and

```
movimentacoes_ref =  firebaseref
                    .child("movimentacao")
                    .child(id_Usuario)
                    .child(mesAno.trim()); // give me a mesAno node in firebase.
```

Comment: Actually," .child(mesAno.trim())" it seems do not work properly unless we pass a complete " String myNodeName = mesAno.trim() "and after that " .child(myNodename)" to create it. Sorry for that.